# ASP.NET MVC 4 ViewModel object lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, object, lifecycle

In my view I have a ViewModel, but I'd like to know, how long is this object "alive" in my web application. Is it just available in the view, or maybe through all the session long... =) Hugs.

Comment: I think viewModels are transient, I don´t see why you would want to share a viewmodel data

Comment: So if I have an object that have many properties, that I have splitted in a few viewmodels and views, what is the best way to get all that information back and put it all in that big object so i can do the persistence?

Comment: to me is more like get the information needed from your persistance storage, pass the properties you need to the viewModel, do modifications you need to do, pass the changes to your action, get again the object from the persistance layer and use TryUpdateModel(myEntity) with the new changes, and update the persistance layer, other alternative could be to put the whole object in cache or in the user session...

Comment: I have all that in mind. My most difficulty is figure how get the data from the forms splitted in all views and put it all together in my object. The situation is, i have a person, where i ask the user to fill the personal data, the academic data, the professional data, etc... that's because i have different actions calling different views... one for each portion of data... but in my back end i have one single entity that is person with all that atributes...

Comment: try to join the room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/39383/casual-conversation-mvc4?tab=general we can discuss it in more detail